# Facebook sharing is not working

Tags: ios, ios8

I am facing one issue, in 64 bit architecture iOS device the sharing feature (Twitter and Facebook) is not working.
When same code I am running in 32 Bit architecture iOS device it's working fine.
I have changed the architecture also as **armv7  armv7s arm64**. But still I am facing the same issue.

Here is my code:

```
/* Facebook sharing  */

SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [controller setInitialText:ARTICLE_GLOBAL_Title];
        [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"144X144.png"]];
        [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ARTICLE_GLOBAL_Link]];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here is the output:

> plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post interrupted Hub connection error
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)" (connection to service named
>   com.apple.share.Facebook.post) UserInfo=0x7f839249d090
>   {NSDebugDescription=connection to service named
>   com.apple.share.Facebook.post
>   }

Comment: Sometimes its working, but sometime is doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look it helps u.

```
SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
    {
        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
        {
            NSLog(@"User Cancelled");
            [callout dismiss];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Item successfully posted on your wall.");
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Hello world." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [callout dismiss];
        }

        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    };

    controller.completionHandler = myBlock;
    //Adding the Text to the facebook post value from iOS
    controller.title = lblTitle.text;
    [controller addImage:imagenews.image];
```